# Next and Prev buttons based on label

Tags: blogger

I tried to make the next button and prev in blogger but it didn't work. The button appears but there is an error.

1. On the first page there should only be a Next button, but instead there is a Prev button that lead to the last page
2. The same thing happened on pages 2-30s, There are only prev buttons that lead to the last page
3. For pages 31-60s the button works well, but somehow page 31 only has a next button, even though there should be a next and prev button

The Code

```xml
<b:includable id='pager_chapter' var='type'>
  <b:if expr:cond='data:post.labels any (l => l.name != data:type.name)'>
    <script type='text/javascript'>var selectchap = false;</script>
  </b:if>
  <b:if expr:cond='data:post.labels any (l => l.name == data:type.name)'>
    <script type='text/javascript'>var selectchap = true;</script>
  </b:if>
  <b:loop index='i' values='data:post.labels' var='label'>
    <b:if cond='data:i == 0'>
      <div class='pager-js' id='pager-js'>
        <div class='_prev' id='prevjs'><a class='pager-js-nolink'><i class='far fa-caret-square-left'/></a></div>
        <div class='_index' id='indexjs'><a class='pager-js-nolink'><i class='far fa-list-alt'/></a></div>
        <div class='_next' id='nextjs'><a class='pager-js-nolink'><i class='far fa-caret-square-right'/></a></div>
      </div>
      <script type='text/javascript'>
        var postPrev = "<i class='fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-left'/>";
        var postNext = "<i class='fas fa-arrow-alt-circle-right'/>";
        var postIndex = "<i class='fas fa-list-ul'/>";
        var postID = <data:post.id/>;
        /*<![CDATA[*/
            if (selectchap == false) {
              var yktocs = function(data) {
                var i = 0;
                for (; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++) {
                  var j = 0;
                  for (; j < data.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
                    if ("alternate" == data.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel) {
                      var entityUrl = data.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
                      break
                    }
                  }
                  document.getElementById("indexjs").innerHTML = "<a href='" + entityUrl + "' title='Index Novel'>" + postIndex + "</a>"
                }
              };
              var ykpager = function(data) {
                var node = {
                  postlist: []
                };
                var i = 0;
                for (; i < data.feed.entry.length; i++) {
                  var j = 0;
                  for (; j < data.feed.entry[i].link.length; j++) {
                    if ("alternate" == data.feed.entry[i].link[j].rel) {
                      var murl = data.feed.entry[i].link[j].href;
                      break
                    }
                  }
                  var videoId = data.feed.entry[i].id.$t;
                  var CAPTURE_ID = videoId.substr(51, 19);
                  node.postlist.push({
                    url: murl,
                    id: CAPTURE_ID
                  })
                }
                var v = node.postlist.findIndex((timeline_mode) => {
                  return timeline_mode.id == postID
                });
                var id = v + 1;
                var cbs = node.postlist[id];
                if (null != cbs) {
                  var g = Object.values(cbs)[0];
                  var lnkDiv = document.getElementById("prevjs");
                  lnkDiv.innerHTML = "<a href='" + g + "' title='Chapter Prev'>" + postPrev + "</a>"
                }
                var q = v - 1;
                var val = node.postlist[q];
                if (null != val) {
                  var k = Object.values(val)[0];
                  lnkDiv = document.getElementById("nextjs");
                  lnkDiv.innerHTML = "<a href='" + k + "' title='Chapter Next'>" + postNext + "</a>"
                }
              }
              } else {
                document.write("<style>.pager-js{display:none;}</style>")
              };
/*]]>*/</script>
      <script defer='defer' expr:src='"/feeds/posts/summary/-/" + data:label.name + "?alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=ykpager"' type='text/javascript'/>
      <script defer='defer' expr:src='"/feeds/posts/summary/-/" + data:type.name + "/" + data:label.name + "?orderby=published&amp;alt=json-in-script&amp;callback=yktocs&amp;max-results=1"' type='text/javascript'/>
    </b:if>
  </b:loop>
</b:includable>
```

Comment: Hi Fauzan. Is this code base on a sample? If so, please add a link to it.

Comment: What is variable `type` referring to ?

Comment: Sorry.. but i even dont understand about that... The sample can you see on https://animanganewsnetwork.blogspot.com/....